# Why N[vector[[j]]] or NumberForm[vector[[j]]] not working?

Tags: number-representation

Why is N not giving the approximate result (removing the .)?

```
vectorj = Table[j, {j, 0, 0.1, 0.01}]
N[vectorj[[1]], 0]
(*out=0.*)
```

or

```
N[vectorj, 0]
```

or

```
NumberForm[vectorj[[1]], 0]
```

`Rationalize` does the job.

Comment: Use `Round` instead.  `N[x,0]` would give a result with zero precision (i.e. something useless).  Look up `Precision`.

Comment: What is the expected output of `N[vectorj, 0]`?

Comment: @Kuba expected output is 0 rather than 0.

Comment: I know that, what about the rest of the list?

Answer (score 3):

It's the expected result from N. The result of N is an approximate result but not an exact result.

In:

```
vectorj = Table[j, {j, 0, 0.1, 0.01}]

N[vectorj[[1]], 0] // Head
0 // Head

N[vectorj[[1]], 0] // Accuracy 
0 // Accuracy
```

Out:

```
{0., 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1}
Real
Integer
307.653
\[Infinity]
```

Workaround:

In:

```
xs = Table[x/100, {x, 0, 10, 1}]
xs // N
```

Out:

```
{0, 1/100, 1/50, 3/100, 1/25, 1/20, 3/50, 7/100, 2/25, 9/100, 1/10}
{0., 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1}
```